# Setting default values to inputs in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an Angular directive element with some inputs, and depending on the attributes of the element, the inputs should be set with default values. Here is the directive:

```
.directive('zoneType', ['$compile', function(){
    restrict: "E",
    require: "^?ngModel",
    templateUrl: "zone.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
         if(!ngModel) return;

         var temp = 0;
         var press = 0;

         if(attrs.region=="top"){
            temp = 60;
            press = 2;
         }else if(attrs.region=="bottom"){
            temp = 20;
            press = 0.4;
         }

         element.find("#gas1").val(temp);
         element.find("#gas2").val(press);

         ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
         ngModel.$render();
}]);
```

and the template looks like this

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input placeholder="Gas1" id="gas1" class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="$root.zone[$index].gas1"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <input placeholder="Gas2" id="gas2" class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="$root.zone[$index].gas2"/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The $index is necessary because the form is inside an angular Tabset.

I'm declaring the element like this

```
<zone-type region='top' ng-model='zone'></zone-type>
```

The template is loading correctly, but the values are not being set, is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.directive('zoneType', ['$compile', function() {
            restrict: "E",
            require: "^?ngModel",  // <<<<< don't know if you need this.
            templateUrl: "zone.html",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                scope.temp = 0;
                scope.press = 0;

                if (attrs.region == "top") {
                    scope.temp = 60;
                    scope.press = 2;
                } else if (attrs.region == "bottom") {
                    scope.temp = 20;
                    scope.press = 0.4;
                }
            }]);
```

And your html should be:

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Gas1" id="gas1" class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="temp"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Gas2" id="gas2" class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="press"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

You really don't need id="gas1" and id="gas2" unless you have a need to use them in your code.  Angular will do the two way binding because you have ng-model.
When using ng-model, Angular will bind temp to any scope.temp.

So later in your code, if you change temp like scope.temp = 'some value', that value is shown in the browser automatically, although you might have to call scope.$apply() or scope.$digest().

Comment: It works! But this directive repeats in other tabs, how can I access the "temp" and "press" for each tab, in the controller?

Comment: How is the scope defined for the directive.  It's best to have the scope isolated, especially when you plan on having the same directive appear multiple times in a page.